# Show that $\langle y^1 - y^2 , x^1 - x^2 \rangle \geq 0 $

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, subgradient

I am trying do this exercise:

**Exercise:**  Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a convex funciton. Show that:
$$\langle y^1 - y^2 , x^1 - x^2 \rangle \geq 0, \qquad \forall x^i \in \mathbb{R}^n, \forall y^i \in \partial f(x^i), i= 1,2.$$

**Notation:** $\partial f(\star)$ means subdifferential of $f$ in $\star$.

And we know the following defenition:

Let $f : X \in \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a convex function, then

$$f(x) - f(y) \leq \langle  \partial f(y)  ,  x - y  \rangle$$.

**My attemp:**

Since $f$ is convex, by defenition above:

$$f(x^1) - f(x^2) \leq \langle  \partial f(x^2)  ,  x^1 - x^2  \rangle, \qquad \forall x^1,x^2 \in \mathbb{R^n}$$

Let $ y^2 \in \partial f(x^2)$ and some inequality properties, we obtain:

$$f(x^1) - f(x^2) - \langle  y^2  ,  x^1 - x^2  \rangle \leq 0 $$

---

I believe wich by iteration or anything similar we can "transform" $f(x^1)- f(x^2)$ in derivate of one point in $D$ (f dominian)and developing the inner product we got what we wanted. But I cannot undertsand one way to do that. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inequality is incorrect, it should be
$$
f(x) - f(y) \geq \langle \partial f(y), x-y\rangle.
$$
that is, a convex function always lies above its supporting hyperplane.

Let $y_1\in \partial f(x_1)$ and $y_2\in \partial f(x_2)$. Then,
$$
f(x_2) - f(x_1) \geq \langle y_1, x_2 - x_1\rangle
$$
and
$$
f(x_1) - f(x_2) \geq \langle y_2, x_1 - x_2\rangle
$$
Summing these inequalities yields,
$$
0 \geq \langle y_1, x_2 - x_1\rangle + \langle y_2, x_1 - x_2\rangle = \langle y_1-y_2, x_2 - x_1\rangle 
$$
and the result follows.

Comment: Thanks for the help!